# Raspberry pi with SIM7600E not connecting to internet automatically after reboot

Tags: internet

Please note that I have a Raspberry pi 4 and a SIM7600E-H1C module and I want my Raspberry pi to be connected to the internet all the time. So I used the SIM7600 module, plugged in and inserted the SIM card. I can provide internet to Raspberry pi using this command[image]and the IP of both SIM7600 and Raspberry pi must match in order to use the internet, for example:[image]but my problem is When the Raspberry pi Reboot and turn it back on Refuses to connect automatically as expected So I have to re-enter the sudo command every time my computer reboots.[image] I want SIM7600E works like an aircard that inserts a SIM card and plugs it in to use the internet right away. Can anyone help me with this? Or is there a way to set the IP somewhere?

I follow this website https://www.elementzonline.com/blog/accessing-internet-(jio-sim)-in-sim7600-4g-modem-v2.0-with-Raspberry-pi-using-qmi-interface

Comment: Have you updated using `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt full-upgrade` specifically?  Then do a reboot.  Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a python script that is executed automatically at reboot.

The python script only needs to do `os.system('sudo ifup wwan0')`

Comment: Why do you need Python3? Just run `ifup` (with sudo if needed).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a bash script + udev rule to detect the interface and execute your script. For example, create the file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-simcom.rules.

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="net", KERNEL=="wwan*", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/simcom.sh '%E{INTERFACE}'"
```

That means when a wwan* interface is detected, it will execute the script located at /usr/local/bin/simcom.sh and pass to it the interface name (wwan0 for example).

When you create this rule, it will not be executed until reboot or if you reload your rules with:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger
```

Then you will need to create that simcom.sh file and execute your comands like

File: /usr/local/bin/simcom.sh

```
ip link set $1 down
echo 'Y' # etc...
```

Remember to make it executable with `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/simcom.sh`

---

An alternative is change the SIM7600 mode and use RNDIS instead of QMI, which is easier to setup but you also will need a small script to get IP with dhclient ir udhcpc.

The interface will be renamed to usb0 instead of wwan0 and you will only need a couple of commands.

A couple of years ago I answered a question before with the instructions here: [SIM7600 as RNDIS interface for Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121873/sim7600-as-rndis-interface-for-raspberry-pi)

Hope it helps!